# Creating a variable from json data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a page setup so that its grabbing data from an external JSON about football/soccer matches, I am applying some extra data for a match report from a database table hosted by my website.

Within the json data I get the following three variables which i want to use:

```
$match['id']
$match['home-team']['name']
$match['away-team']['name']
```

In my database i have the following 4 data sets

- id
- gameid
- author
- matchlink

What i am trying to accomplish is using the json data to create a variable of the match['id'] into a variable for use like so.

```
$gameid_{$match['id']} = $match['home-team']['name'] ' vs ' $match['away-team']['name']
```

for example
if the match id was: 123456
if the home team name was: Town FC
if the away team name was: City FC

then i would get a variable like this:
`$gameid_123456 = Town FC vs City FC`

i have tried the following:

```
foreach ( $json_decoded as $match ) {
    ${$match['id']} =  $match['home-team']['name']. 'vs' .$match['away-team']['name'];
}
global ${$row->gameid};

echo ${$row->gameid};
```

but it does not display anything.

Am i missing something or is that completely wrong?

Thanks in advance

Adam

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to use an array? $gameid[$match['id']]

Comment: oh duh ofcourse... eugh just use the foreach loop to create another array, thanks i just needed that outside perspective

Comment: When I see `$gameid_123456` I see a red flag waving. That most likely needs to be `$gameid['123456']`.  So I wonder if you want something like this `$game[ $match['id'] ] = $match['home-team']['name'] . ' vs ' . $match['away-team]['name']`

Comment: Tim, you are correct, I am creating the array instead, i assume i would then just call $game[$row->gameid] to echo it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone comes across this and would like further assistance I created a variable array, here is how the foreach code worked:

```
global $match_data;
$match_data = array ();

foreach ( $json_decoded_r as $match ){
    $match_data[ $match['id'] ] = $match['home-team']['name']. ' vs ' .$match['away-team']['name'];
}
```

then whilst from the database which contains this variable which contains the gameid

```
global $match_data;
echo $match_data[ $row->gameid ];
```

So for instance with my json echoing out the `$match_data[367327]` resulted in `Aveley vs Hastings United`